# How to supernet a group of subnets together?

Tags: subnet

For example, I have these hosts from different subnets:

```
192.168.0.1/27 
192.168.0.33/27
192.168.0.65/27
192.168.0.97/27
```

How can I supernet them together and find the network address and mask? (These will be used in a static routing table)

Answer (score 1):

You want the `netmask` command:

```
$ netmask -c 192.168.0.1/27 192.168.0.33/27 192.168.0.65/27 192.168.0.97/27
    192.168.0.0/25
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I manually work out the network address and mask?

Comment: @moonxdd Utilities exist so we don't have to do binary math by hand. There are ways to manually do this, but that kind of "show your work" is above and beyond for this site.

Comment: Of course it isn't above and beyond a site for pro sysadminship to understand how subnetting/supernetting works @84104. My take is that if one learns how to do this easy math by hand, one starts to understand how the subnetmask works. That's when one begins to ask interesting questions, lke how the mac address is used in conjunction with the ip address. After understanding the math and what it does it is not neccessary but a matter of choice wether to use a calculator for speed.